# How to check columns and put a specific value to another column in another dataframe accordingly in an efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`.
Both have the same IDs. In `df2`, one ID is in multiple rows (none or one of the `columnB` can have value 'a' and on every row, there is another value in `columnC).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['111.111', '222.222', '333.333','444.444], 'columnA': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]}) # or columnA does not has to be defined yet
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['111.111', '111.111','111.111', '222.222' ,'222.222', '333.333', '333.333', '444.444'],
'columnB': [np.nan,'a',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
'columnC':['0432', '0987','5460','0955','4356','6029','7329','9006']})
```

That looks like:

```
df1                   df2
ID       columnA       ID     columnB   columnC
111.111              111.111             0432
222.222              111.111     a       0987
333.333              111.111             5460
444.444              222.222             0955
                     222.222             4356
                     333.333             6029
                     333.333             7329
                     444.444             9006
```

My goal:
If `columnB == 'a'` OR none of `columnC` isin(validValues), I want to put the value 'AA' in the `columnA` of `df1` with the same `ID` where one of the conditions gave true.

I need an **efficient** way for this.

Let's say `validValues = {'0987', '2638', '5460', '9386'}`

expected `df1`:

```
ID      columnA
111.111
222.222    AA
333.333
444.444    AA
```

I was trying the following 'til now:

```
df2['temp']=df2['columnB']

tmp_df = df2.groupby('ID').temp.apply(lambda x: 'AA' if (x=='a').any() else ' ')


tmp_df=tmp_df.to_frame()

df1['columnA']=df1.merge(tmp_df, how='outer',
               left_on=df1.ID, 
               right_on=tmp_df.index).drop('key_0', axis=1)['temp']


df2['temp']=df2['columnc']
tmp_df = df2.groupby('ID').temp.apply(lambda x: 'AA' if (x.isin(validValues)).any() else ' ')
tmp_df=tmp_df.to_frame()

df1['columnA']=df1.merge(tmp_df, how='outer',
               left_on=df1.ID, 
               right_on=tmp_df.index).drop('key_0', axis=1)['temp']
```

One problem is, that the 2nd merge overrides the first one. The solution is bad at all.

Also, it would be nice to *delete* thoose IDs where 'AA' was putted in in df1 *from `df2`*.

Comment: It will be easier for people to answer your question if you can show code to generate a small sample dataframe and then show the outcome you expect.

Comment: you're right, I tried to provide an example and the expected result now @ASGM

Comment: Thanks - can you edit it so it can be easily pasted into someone else's code?  That is, in the form `df = pd.DataFrame( ... )`?  That will make it much simpler for someone to answer your question.

Comment: done @ASGM : - )

Answer (score 0):

```
df2IDs = df2[(df2['columnB'] == 'a') | (df2['columnC'].isin(validValues))][ID].tolist()

df1.loc[df1['ID'].isin(df2IDs), 'columnA'] = 'a'
```

1) First filter df2 for the where columnB is a or columnC is in your validvalues, look at the ID column and save it to a list.

2) Take that list, and look in df1 for where the ID's match, look at columnA and set it equal to 'a'.

**EDIT**

```
df2IDs = df2.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x:any(x.columnB == 'a') | all(np.logical_not(x.columnC.isin(validValues))))['ID']

df1.loc[df1['ID'].isin(df2IDs), 'columnA'] = 'a'
```

I misunderstood your question. The first statement will return the groups whenever **any** of the member contain 'a' or that **all** the member's are not in valid values.

Comment: I edited your answer because what I want is, that the second condition is negotiated: if none of the columnC-values are in `validValues`, get `ID`. But this does not work for 444.444, even if its `columnC: '9006'` is not in `validValues`. I just get `df2IDs='111.111'` . I would expect `df2IDs={'111.111','444,444'}`